# Wordpress - Add comma to all but last item, remove underscore

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I'm using the [advanced custom field](http://plugins.elliotcondon.com/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin for Wordpress to show the results of checkboxes. I have what I want working, I just want to tidy up the code and add the following:

1. Remove the underscore from the social media tag (some kind of stripping out???).
2. If possible I'd like to show a comma after each "tag" but not if it's the last one.

Here's my [test page](http://teamworksdesign.com/v2/our-work/dtr-medical/), they're the blue "tags" under the discipline section.

Here's my code:

```
    <?php 
$catNames = array( 'branding','creative','development','exhibition','packaging','print','seo','social_media','usability','web','advertising','campaign','content','feasibility','publishing','research','strategy');

foreach($catNames as $name){
    if(in_array($name, get_field('categories') )){
echo '<a href="/tags/design/'.$name.'" title="'.$name.'">'.strtoupper($name).'</a>';       
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can't you just loop using `foreach( get_field('categories') as $category )` and print the `a` tags for that category?

Comment: Cheers, I don't really know enough to try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it is pretty basic, you just have to do a loop. I could have write something better with more information... anyway this should do exactly what your code did but in a loop.

```
<?php 
$catNames = array( 'branding','creative','development','exhibition','packaging','print','seo','social_media','usability','web','advertising','campaign','content','feasibility','publishing','research','strategy');

foreach($catNames as $name){
    if(in_array($name, get_field('categories') )){ //I don't know what this is suppose to do
echo '<a href="/tags/design/'.$name.'" title="'.$name.'">'.strtoupper($name).'</a>';       
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to put a comma on the end but not if it's the last item. Also, is it possible to convert the word "social_media" to "Social Media" in the displayed link text (not the href)?

Comment: The best thing to do would be to get the categories, not just the names. So you could use every values. I'll make you an example.

Comment: Ok thanks, the get_field('categories') is linking it to the advanced custom field from the Wordpress plugin mentioned in the question.

Comment: I think this is the closest to being right. Just need a way to replace the _ with a space and add a comma after each tag except the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
<?php foreach( get_field('categories') as $category ): ?>    
    <a href="/tags/design/<?php echo $category ?>" title="<?php echo ucwords($category) ?>"><?php echo ucwords($category) ?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Cool, that works, thanks. Is it possible to put a comma on the end but not if it's the last item.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this should be better

```
<?php
$catNames = array( 'branding','creative','development','exhibition','packaging','print','seo','social_media','usability','web','advertising','campaign','content','feasibility','publishing','research','strategy');
    foreach($catNames as $name){
        $theID = get_cat_ID($name); // get the ID of each category
        echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($theID).'" title="'.$theID->name.'">'.$theID->name.'</a>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, the get_field('categories') is linking it to the advanced custom field from the Wordpress plugin mentioned in the question. Without it nothing appears. As a result nothing appeared with this, but it does with your first answer.

Comment: I wouldn't know where to add it sorry!

Comment: Just add it after the foreach, like in the first answer

Comment: But this  will make it appear on the last item, it looks a bit rubbish.

Comment: Ok sorry it should have been  get_cat_name($theID) instead of $theID->name